# Best Practice - To generate a RUN_ID for my SAS ETL

Tags: sas, etl

I have a SAS ETL Process which runs daily and I keep track of the run using a control table. I've been using sequential numbers that I generate for each run. But is there a better or Best Practice?

My Process of generating `run_id` is:

```
data have; 
input run_id date $; 
datalines; 
0 12dec2017 
1 21jan2018 
2 1feb2018 
; 
run; 
proc sql; select max(run_id) into :id from have ; quit;
```

I get the max+1 and use it as the next `run_id`. In the example above my next `run_id` will be 3 (2+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a datetime stamp as run_id  instead of a sequence so the number itself will be meaningful; it can be char or numeric but in this format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` so it will be easier to sort by.

This code will generate the id for you:

```
data new; 
run_id=&id+1; 
id_char="%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.)_%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(time(),time6.) ,:))"; 
id_num=%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.)%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(time(),time6.) ,:)); 
run;
```

Output:

```
run_id=3 id_char=20180517_1234 id_num=201805171234
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 proc sql; select max(run_id)+1 into :id from have ; quit;
```